# How to add multiple custom codes into rdlc and call separately in expression

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

How to add multiple custom codes into rdlc and call separately in expression ?

What happened is I have already put one set of vb.code Custom Code into my RDLC report. Now I have to use another different set of Custom Code in the same report and call each of them from expression to use in different places.
Is it possible to Combine two sets of Codes into one report? If so, how do I achieve that?
Example for one set of VbCode: 
http://www.neodynamic.com/demo-faq/barcode-reporting-services/using-barcode-dll-component.aspx

And another set is:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/32f28407-e1ca-457e-92fd-d292e32dde4e/limit-no-of-columns-in-ssrs-matrix-report

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can declare multiple custom functions in a report. And you can manage to combine their results in a single expression. i.e `="My Average is: " & Code.GetAverage(params) & "and my standard deviation is: " & Code.GetSD(params)`. Note in my example the custom functions return primitive data types if yours do not you will have to manage to show them correctly in your report.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta thanks...finally I get it working no matter how many custom functions inside a report.